# Rails app user session not working properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I’m building my first Rails app, and for some odd reason, it seems like user sessions are being thrown away and I don’t know how to fix it. What I mean is, my index template is set up so `<% if user_signed_in? %>` is true, they’ll just see the app with all their data, else they’ll see a sign up page. Everything *seems* to work, but when you refresh the page after signing in, things like the sign out (`destroy_user_session_path`) button just disappear.

Below is my code. Ignore all Angular stuff – I’m switching away from it because I decided to use it prematurely.

```erb
<% if user_signed_in? %>

<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>

<div class="site_container" ng-controller="SubmissionsCtrl">

    <div class= "row-fluid" id="indexrow">
        <div class="span7">
            <form id="postSubmit" action="/submissions" method="post">
                    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
                    <label for="titleinput">Title</label> 
                    <input type="text" id="titleinput" name="title" placeholder="Title"></input>
                    <label for="contentinput">Content</label>
                    <textarea id="contentinput" rows="6" name="content" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:10px">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            <div id="submission-list-container">
                <ul id="indexSubmissions">
                        <% current_user.submissions.each do |i| %>
                            <%= i.title %>
                            <%= i.content %>
                        <% end %>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<% else%>


<div id="intro_page_center">
<h2 id="big_intro">Explore your mind.</h2>
<div id="registration_login">
    <a href="users/sign_in" class="sign_in_up">Log in</a>
    <a href="users/sign_up" class="sign_in_up">Sign up</a>
</div>
<div id="about_container">
    <ul id="about_braindb">
        <li>
            <h3>Save <small>Save stories, videos, recipes, and anything else that defines you.</small></h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>Learn <small>Discover patterns, connections, and meaningful context in everything you save to BrainDB.</small></h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>Grow <small>Utilize your newfound abilities to read your subconcious through idea generation, collaboration, and more.</small></h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<% end%>
```

Any idea what it could be? I saw somewhere that it could be related to Rails 3 security and my POST form submission, but I lost the page and couldn’t find more info on it.

Comment: A good place to start would be to show us how you've defined `user_signed_in?`.

Comment: I'm utilizing Devise.

Comment: can you print in your view the following : `<%= session.inspect %>`

Comment: {"session_id"=>"21667cd15c9eda50a1fcf239c7338efb", "_csrf_token"=>"1wIrvpC7TFwlgsFCjDo5I2wh5tgOxx9Z1aPjtOAJ57c=", "warden.user.user.key"=>[[2], "$2a$10$rzXriodSWMd34UJShwQpo."]}

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the device before_filter added in your controller?

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: Yes, it's in my submissions controller.